# how to start using ormlite for android coding with a mac?

Tags: android, ormlite

Ok i know i might be flamed  for the noobness of this question but please pardon me! I'm trying to start using ORMLite for my android app but am at a loss even at their documentation. Seems like the documentation is quite abstract as well - I've downloaded the `ormlite-android-4.2.3.jar` and `ormlite-core-4.2.3.jar` but cannot run them with my Mac.

I've tried to google for how to set up ormlite but there is no relevant results all pointing to the same document pdf for ormlite. Is there any more detailed steps? How should I be doing it?  Any directions?  Thanks!

Comment: This has no relevance to what OS you are doing.  Your accepted answer will work on computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah I've found out how to use it, its by copying and pasting it into the project folder of your android app !

Just in case anyone want to find out how to start using ORMlite ! :)